# What does this Numba error message mean and how can I solve the problem?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I tried speeding up my own, slow implementation of a marching cubes algorithm with numba but I get this error:

```
pygame 2.1.3 (SDL 2.0.22, Python 3.11.1)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Programme\Marching_Cubes\main.py", line 72, in <module>
    app = GraphicsEngine()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Programme\Marching_Cubes\main.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.mesh = Mesh(self)
                ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Programme\Marching_Cubes\mesh.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.world = Chunk_VAO(app)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Programme\Marching_Cubes\world.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.get_vertex_data()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Programme\Marching_Cubes\world.py", line 83, in get_vertex_data
    chunk[2] = self.c_vbo.get_vertex_data(chunk[1])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numba\experimental\jitclass\boxing.py", line 61, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
- Resolution failure for literal arguments:
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
- Resolution failure for literal arguments:
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Cannot unify array(float32, 1d, C) and array(float32, 2d, C) for 'vertices.4', defined at c:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Programme\Marching_Cubes\chunk_vbo.py (331)

File "chunk_vbo.py", line 331:
    def march_cube(self, pos, voxel_grid):
        <source elided>

            p1, p2 = EDGES[int(edge_index)]
            ^

During: typing of assignment at c:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Programme\Marching_Cubes\chunk_vbo.py (331)

File "chunk_vbo.py", line 331:
    def march_cube(self, pos, voxel_grid):
        <source elided>

            p1, p2 = EDGES[int(edge_index)]
            ^

- Resolution failure for non-literal arguments:
None

During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction((<class 'numba.core.types.misc.ClassInstanceType'>, 'march_cube') for instance.jitclass.Chunk_VBO#2047f71e150<>)
During: typing of call at c:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Programme\Marching_Cubes\chunk_vbo.py (300)


File "chunk_vbo.py", line 300:
    def get_vertex_data(self, voxel_grid):
        <source elided>
                for x in range(RES-1):
                    new = self.march_cube(np.array([x,y,z]), voxel_grid)
                    ^

- Resolution failure for non-literal arguments:
None

During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction((<class 'numba.core.types.misc.ClassInstanceType'>, 'get_vertex_data') for instance.jitclass.Chunk_VBO#2047f71e150<>)
During: typing of call at <string> (3)


File "<string>", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

the code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
from numba.experimental import jitclass


RES = 17
POINTS = np.array([
            [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
        ], dtype=np.int8)
EDGES = np.array([
    [0, 1],
    [1, 3],
    [3, 2],
    [2, 0],
    [4, 5],
    [5, 7],
    [7, 6],
    [6, 4],
    [0, 4],
    [1, 5],
    [3, 7],
    [2, 6],
], dtype = np.int8    )
TRIANGULATIONS = np.array([
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 8, 8, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 11, 0, 0, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 9, 3, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 1, 2, 11, 9, 1, 11, 8, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 2, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 10, 0, 3, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 2, 2, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 2, 3, 8, 10, 2, 8, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 10, 3, 3, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 0, 1, 10, 8, 0, 10, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 3, 0, 9, 11, 3, 9, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 10, 8, 8, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 1, 4, 8, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 4, 9, 1, 7, 4, 1, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 3, 2, 8, 7, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 11, 7, 4, 2, 11, 4, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 11, 0, 9, 1, 4, 8, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 4, 4, 1, 7, 7, 1, 2, 7, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 8, 1, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 3, 3, 4, 0, 10, 2, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 2, 9, 9, 2, 0, 7, 4, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 9, 7, 9, 2, 9, 10, 2, 3, 7, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 10, 3, 3, 10, 11, 4, 8, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 0, 7, 0, 1, 10, 7, 0, 10, 7, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 8, 9, 3, 0, 9, 11, 3, 9, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 11, 4, 9, 11, 9, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 3, 9, 4, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 5, 5, 0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 8, 4, 5, 3, 8, 5, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 11, 5, 9, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 11, 0, 0, 11, 8, 5, 9, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 0, 0, 5, 1, 11, 3, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 8, 2, 8, 4, 5, 2, 8, 5, 2, 5, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 4, 1, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 8, 1, 10, 2, 5, 9, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 5, 10, 2, 4, 5, 2, 0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 8, 8, 5, 3, 3, 5, 10, 3, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 3, 10, 10, 3, 1, 4, 5, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 9, 10, 0, 1, 10, 8, 0, 10, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 10, 4, 10, 3, 10, 11, 3, 0, 4, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 8, 5, 10, 8, 10, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 7, 7, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 9, 0, 3, 5, 9, 3, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 0, 8, 7, 1, 0, 7, 5, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 7, 1, 1, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 7, 7, 9, 8, 2, 11, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 0, 5, 0, 11, 0, 2, 11, 7, 5, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 11, 3, 7, 0, 8, 7, 1, 0, 7, 5, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 11, 1, 11, 7, 1, 7, 5, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 7, 9, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 2, 1, 3, 9, 0, 3, 5, 9, 3, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 0, 10, 0, 8, 7, 10, 0, 7, 10, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 2, 5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 8, 5, 8, 7, 1, 10, 3, 10, 11, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 10, 0, 0, 10, 11, 0, 11, 7, 0, 7, 5, 0, 5, 9, -1],
[8, 7, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 5, 10, 0, 10, 11, 0, 11, 3, -1],
[5, 11, 7, 10, 11, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 0, 7, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 9, 7, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 8, 8, 1, 3, 6, 7, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 7, 2, 2, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 7, 8, 0, 6, 7, 0, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 7, 2, 2, 7, 3, 9, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 2, 9, 2, 7, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 2, 1, 11, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 10, 3, 8, 0, 7, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 2, 2, 9, 10, 7, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 7, 11, 8, 2, 3, 8, 10, 2, 8, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 10, 6, 7, 1, 10, 7, 3, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 10, 0, 0, 10, 8, 8, 10, 6, 8, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 10, 0, 10, 6, 7, 0, 10, 7, 0, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 7, 10, 7, 8, 10, 8, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 8, 6, 6, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 3, 11, 6, 0, 3, 6, 4, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 6, 8, 8, 6, 4, 1, 0, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 4, 11, 4, 9, 1, 11, 4, 1, 11, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 8, 3, 2, 4, 8, 2, 6, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 0, 2, 8, 3, 2, 4, 8, 2, 6, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 6, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 8, 6, 6, 8, 11, 1, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 10, 2, 6, 3, 11, 6, 0, 3, 6, 4, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 10, 0, 10, 2, 4, 8, 6, 8, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 6, 3, 3, 6, 4, 3, 4, 9, 3, 9, 10, 3, 10, 2, -1],
[1, 10, 6, 1, 6, 8, 6, 4, 8, 3, 1, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 10, 0, 10, 6, 0, 6, 4, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 3, 3, 9, 10, 3, 10, 6, 3, 6, 4, 3, 4, 8, -1],
[4, 10, 6, 9, 10, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 9, 6, 7, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 11, 6, 8, 0, 3, 9, 4, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 5, 5, 0, 4, 11, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 6, 7, 5, 8, 4, 5, 3, 8, 5, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 7, 7, 2, 6, 9, 4, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 4, 0, 7, 8, 0, 6, 7, 0, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 2, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 8, 8, 5, 1, 8, 1, 2, 8, 2, 6, 8, 6, 7, -1],
[6, 7, 11, 5, 9, 4, 1, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 4, 7, 11, 6, 0, 3, 8, 2, 1, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 11, 6, 2, 5, 10, 2, 4, 5, 2, 0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 7, 11, 3, 8, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 5, 10, -1],
[9, 4, 5, 7, 10, 6, 7, 1, 10, 7, 3, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 4, 8, 0, 1, 8, 1, 10, 8, 10, 7, 7, 10, 6, -1],
[6, 7, 10, 10, 7, 3, 10, 3, 0, 10, 0, 4, 10, 4, 5, -1],
[4, 5, 8, 8, 5, 10, 8, 10, 6, 8, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 6, 5, 9, 11, 6, 9, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 9, 9, 3, 5, 5, 3, 11, 5, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 8, 1, 8, 6, 8, 11, 6, 5, 1, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 6, 3, 6, 5, 3, 5, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 6, 3, 6, 5, 9, 3, 6, 9, 3, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 6, 9, 0, 6, 0, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 8, 8, 2, 6, 8, 6, 5, 8, 5, 1, 8, 1, 0, -1],
[1, 6, 5, 2, 6, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 10, 9, 6, 5, 9, 11, 6, 9, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 10, 5, 9, 0, 5, 0, 3, 5, 3, 6, 6, 3, 11, -1],
[10, 2, 5, 5, 2, 0, 5, 0, 8, 5, 8, 11, 5, 11, 6, -1],
[10, 2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 11, 5, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 6, 6, 9, 8, 6, 8, 3, 6, 3, 1, 6, 1, 10, -1],
[5, 9, 6, 6, 9, 0, 6, 0, 1, 6, 1, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 3, 0, 5, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 5, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 10, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 0, 5, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 0, 10, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 1, 1, 8, 9, 6, 10, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 10, 5, 2, 11, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 11, 11, 0, 2, 5, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 6, 1, 0, 9, 3, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 6, 10, 11, 1, 2, 11, 9, 1, 11, 8, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 6, 6, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 6, 1, 1, 6, 2, 8, 0, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 9, 5, 6, 0, 9, 6, 2, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 9, 3, 9, 5, 6, 3, 9, 6, 3, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 6, 11, 3, 5, 6, 3, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 6, 11, 5, 11, 0, 11, 8, 0, 1, 5, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 3, 3, 9, 11, 11, 9, 5, 11, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 6, 9, 6, 11, 9, 11, 8, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 8, 5, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, 10, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 8, 7, 9, 1, 0, 10, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 10, 5, 1, 4, 9, 1, 7, 4, 1, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 3, 2, 7, 4, 8, 5, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 6, 4, 11, 7, 4, 2, 11, 4, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 8, 3, 2, 11, 9, 1, 0, 10, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 6, 7, 4, 9, 7, 9, 1, 7, 1, 11, 11, 1, 2, -1],
[2, 1, 6, 6, 1, 5, 8, 7, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 0, 7, 0, 3, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 7, 4, 6, 9, 5, 6, 0, 9, 6, 2, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 6, 9, 9, 6, 2, 9, 2, 3, 9, 3, 7, 9, 7, 4, -1],
[4, 8, 7, 3, 6, 11, 3, 5, 6, 3, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 11, 11, 4, 0, 11, 0, 1, 11, 1, 5, 11, 5, 6, -1],
[4, 8, 7, 11, 3, 0, 11, 0, 9, 11, 9, 6, 6, 9, 5, -1],
[5, 6, 9, 9, 6, 11, 9, 11, 7, 9, 7, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 4, 10, 10, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 10, 4, 4, 10, 9, 3, 8, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 10, 1, 0, 6, 10, 0, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 4, 3, 4, 10, 4, 6, 10, 1, 3, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 4, 10, 10, 4, 6, 3, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 2, 8, 2, 11, 9, 4, 10, 4, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 3, 2, 0, 10, 1, 0, 6, 10, 0, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 11, 1, 1, 11, 8, 1, 8, 4, 1, 4, 6, 1, 6, 10, -1],
[4, 1, 9, 4, 2, 1, 4, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 0, 4, 1, 9, 4, 2, 1, 4, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 6, 0, 0, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 2, 8, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 1, 11, 1, 9, 4, 11, 1, 4, 11, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 4, 1, 1, 4, 6, 1, 6, 11, 1, 11, 8, 1, 8, 0, -1],
[11, 3, 6, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 6, 11, 4, 6, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 7, 6, 10, 8, 7, 10, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 9, 6, 9, 0, 3, 6, 9, 3, 6, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 7, 0, 0, 7, 1, 1, 7, 6, 1, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 10, 7, 10, 1, 7, 1, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 11, 10, 7, 6, 10, 8, 7, 10, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 10, 7, 7, 10, 9, 7, 9, 0, 7, 0, 2, 7, 2, 11, -1],
[11, 3, 2, 1, 0, 8, 1, 8, 7, 1, 7, 10, 10, 7, 6, -1],
[6, 10, 7, 7, 10, 1, 7, 1, 2, 7, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 7, 6, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 1, 9, 8, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 9, 9, 3, 7, 9, 7, 6, 9, 6, 2, 9, 2, 1, -1],
[8, 7, 0, 7, 6, 0, 6, 2, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 2, 3, 6, 2, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 3, 6, 6, 3, 1, 6, 1, 9, 6, 9, 8, 6, 8, 7, -1],
[11, 7, 6, 1, 9, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 3, 6, 6, 3, 0, 6, 0, 8, 6, 8, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 7, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 11, 11, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 11, 11, 5, 7, 0, 3, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 11, 5, 5, 11, 10, 0, 9, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 9, 3, 9, 1, 7, 11, 5, 11, 10, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 2, 10, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 2, 8, 2, 10, 5, 8, 2, 5, 8, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 1, 5, 2, 10, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 2, 2, 5, 7, 2, 7, 8, 2, 8, 9, 2, 9, 1, -1],
[1, 11, 2, 1, 7, 11, 1, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 3, 1, 11, 2, 1, 7, 11, 1, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 5, 0, 5, 11, 5, 7, 11, 2, 0, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 2, 2, 8, 9, 2, 9, 5, 2, 5, 7, 2, 7, 11, -1],
[5, 7, 1, 1, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 7, 0, 1, 7, 1, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 3, 9, 5, 3, 5, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 7, 8, 5, 7, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 5, 4, 8, 10, 5, 8, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 4, 10, 4, 3, 4, 0, 3, 11, 10, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 9, 8, 5, 4, 8, 10, 5, 8, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 11, 4, 11, 10, 4, 10, 5, -1],
[10, 5, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 2, 5, 4, 2, 4, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 0, 3, 2, 10, 3, 10, 5, 3, 5, 8, 8, 5, 4, -1],
[10, 5, 2, 2, 5, 4, 2, 4, 9, 2, 9, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 5, 2, 5, 4, 8, 2, 5, 8, 2, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 11, 11, 1, 5, 11, 5, 4, 11, 4, 0, 11, 0, 3, -1],
[4, 8, 5, 5, 8, 11, 5, 11, 2, 5, 2, 0, 5, 0, 9, -1],
[5, 4, 9, 2, 3, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 8, 5, 8, 3, 5, 3, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 5, 4, 1, 5, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 3, 3, 9, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 4, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 4, 7, 11, 9, 4, 11, 10, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 8, 11, 4, 7, 11, 9, 4, 11, 10, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 4, 1, 4, 7, 11, 1, 4, 11, 1, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 11, 4, 4, 11, 10, 4, 10, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 8, -1],
[9, 4, 7, 9, 7, 2, 7, 3, 2, 10, 9, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 7, 7, 0, 2, 7, 2, 10, 7, 10, 9, 7, 9, 4, -1],
[1, 0, 10, 10, 0, 4, 10, 4, 7, 10, 7, 3, 10, 3, 2, -1],
[7, 8, 4, 10, 1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 7, 2, 7, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 3, 2, 1, 9, 2, 9, 4, 2, 4, 11, 11, 4, 7, -1],
[7, 11, 4, 11, 2, 4, 2, 0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 2, 2, 8, 4, 2, 4, 7, 2, 7, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 4, 1, 4, 7, 1, 7, 3, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 4, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1, 7, 8, 1, 8, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 4, 7, 0, 4, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 8, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 11, 9, 9, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 9, 3, 11, 9, 11, 10, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 10, 0, 8, 10, 8, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 3, 11, 1, 3, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 8, 2, 10, 8, 10, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 2, 10, 0, 2, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 10, 10, 0, 8, 10, 8, 3, 10, 3, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 10, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 11, 1, 9, 11, 9, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 11, 11, 1, 9, 11, 9, 0, 11, 0, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 0, 8, 2, 0, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 11, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 8, 3, 9, 8, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 9, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 3, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],], dtype='i8')


#@jitclass
class Chunk_VBO():
    def __init__(self):       
        pass        
     
    def get_vertex_data(self, voxel_grid):         
        vertices = np.array([], dtype = np.float32)
        # get triangles                 
        for z in range(RES-1):
            for y in range(RES-1):
                for x in range(RES-1):
                    new = self.march_cube(np.array([x,y,z]), voxel_grid)
                    if new.size > 1:
                        if vertices.size < 1:
                            vertices = np.array(new)
                        else:
                            vertices = np.vstack((vertices, new))
                    
        # calculate normals of triangles
        normals = np.zeros(vertices.shape, dtype= np.float32)
    
        for i in range(0,normals.shape[0],3):
            normals[i:i+2] = self.calculate_normal(vertices[i], vertices[i+1], vertices[i+2])
       
        vertex_data = np.hstack([normals, np.array(vertices)])
        return vertex_data
    
    def calculate_normal(self, vertex_1, vertex_2, vertex_3):
        edge_1 = vertex_2 - vertex_1
        edge_2 = vertex_3 - vertex_1
        
        normal = np.cross(edge_1, edge_2)
        return normal
    
    def march_cube(self, pos, voxel_grid):
        point_indeces = np.array([0,0],dtype=np.int8)
        vertices = np.array([], dtype = np.float32)
        triangulation = self.get_triangulation(pos[0],pos[1],pos[2], voxel_grid)
        for edge_index in triangulation:
            if edge_index < 0:
                break
            
            p1, p2 = EDGES[edge_index]
            point1 = POINTS[p1]
            index = pos+point1
            v1 = voxel_grid[index[0]+RES*index[1]+RES*RES*index[2]]
            
            point2 = POINTS[p2]
            index = pos+point2
            v2 = voxel_grid[index[0]+RES*index[1]+RES*RES*index[2]]
            
            vertex = point1 + ((point1 - point2)/(v2 - v1) *v1 ) 
            vertex += pos
            #vertex = (point1 + point2) /2 + pos * 1.1
            if vertices.size < 1:
                vertices = vertex
            else:
                vertices = np.vstack((vertices, vertex))
        return vertices


    def get_triangulation(self, x, y, z, voxel_grid):
        config_index = 0b00000000
        
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[x+RES*y+RES*RES*z]<0) << 0
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[x+RES*y+RES*RES*(z+1)]<0) << 1
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[(x+1)+RES*y+RES*RES*z]<0) << 2
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[(x+1)+RES*y+RES*RES*(z+1)]<0) << 3
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[x+RES*(y+1)+RES*RES*z]<0) << 4
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[x+RES*(y+1)+RES*RES*(z+1)]<0) << 5
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[(x+1)+RES*(y+1)+RES*RES*z]<0) << 6
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[(x+1)+RES*(y+1)+RES*RES*(z+1)]<0) << 7
        
        return TRIANGULATIONS[config_index]
```

The EDGES array is a lookup for which point are connected by an edge. p1 and p2 should be two integers from one line in the EDGES table. Without numba everything works fine (but very slow).

I didn't really try anything because I don't understand the error message, even after googling it.

Comment: The key part of the error is `Cannot unify array(float32, 1d, C) and array(float32, 2d, C)`. It means that the variable is set to both a 1D and 2D array. This is not possible in Numba since the dimension is a part of the type of a variable and variables are statically compiled. Note that `np.array([], dtype = np.float32)` is a 1D array for Numba so you cannot then set the variable to a 2D array (eg. using stack functions).

Comment: Although the Numba documentation advise people not to specify the signature of functions, I strongly advise people to do the opposite since it help a lot during debugging by clearly defining expected types (so then errors are more clear and you can even find typing issues that would not be detected otherwise), and also avoid functions to be compiled lazily at runtime. Signature can be provided using for example `@njit('float32(float32, float32)'` (this is a function taking 2 32-bit floats and returning one).

Comment: Thank you. I think I now know how to work around this issue.

Comment: @Anton15b did you find a good solution? you can Answer your own Question to help the community and gain some reputation!